# azenv2.php ,what is in the error log view?

Tags: log-files

we check in log in DirectAdmin,view many unknow log :

```
[Thu Aug 11 07:59:21.892544 2016] [:error] [pid 17914] [client 117.1.247.114:57814] script '/var/www/html/judge.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Aug 11 08:17:57.803557 2016] [:error] [pid 25831] [client 62.210.78.119:62709] script '/var/www/html/ip4.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Aug 11 08:19:49.586082 2016] [:error] [pid 25167] [client 62.210.111.116:35664] script '/var/www/html/azenv2.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Aug 11 09:48:34.540459 2016] [:error] [pid 9383] [client 91.196.50.33:54301] script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the internet! This is just the internet probing your system looking for vulnerabilities.  Fortunately, (at least in the snippet provided) nothing is being found.

If you are running a Linux Distro you can install and configure [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) which can help lock them out.

<sub>Sure I know this is a dupe multiple times over but I can't find any.</sub>